# How to bind a list using MVC .net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have class `OrderSummaryViewModel`

```
public class OrderSummaryViewModel
    {  
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; } 
        public string DeliveryCondition { get; set; } 
        /// <summary>
        /// Order items
        /// </summary>
        public List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; } 
    }
```

And second class `OrderItem`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Order items
    /// </summary>
    public class OrderItem
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string ItemNumber { get; set; } 
        public string DeliveredQuantity { get; set; } 
        public string fullyDelivered  { get; set; } 
    }
```

And i bind model `OrderSummaryViewModel` into below `.csHTML` view to show the order with its related items.

```
      @model OrderSummaryViewModel

      <div class="baseForm">
            <label>PO Number:</label></td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PurchaseOrderNumber) 
            <label>Delivery Condition:</label> 
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DeliveryCondition) 

            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterGoodsReceipt",FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccessRegisterGoodsReceipt", OnFailure = "OnFailureRegisterGoodsReceipt" }, null))
            {
                var items= Model.Items;
                <table class="dataGrid">
                    @for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var item = items[i];
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemNumber)</td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="fullyDelivered" id="@(item.Id)" name="fullyDelivered" type="checkbox" /> 
                                <input type="text" id="deliveredQuantity@(item.Id)" name="DeliveredQuantity" value="@item.DeliveredQuantity"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table> 
                <button type="submit"  class="button">Submit</button>
            }
     </div>
```

I want to submit the list of items to below action as below

```
public ActionResult RegisterGoodsReceipt(OrderSummaryViewModel order)
{
//to do
}
```

But it always go with null, i tried also to send it as list of items and it gives null also.

```
public ActionResult RegisterGoodsReceipt(List<OrderItem> items)
{
//to do
}
```

so any help regarding this issue?

Comment: `DisplayFor` doesn't `post` the value. You have to maintain them in `hidden fields or TextBoxFor or EditorFor` with proper indexing for list of order items.

Comment: Generate your inputs correctly inside the `for` loop using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].DeliveredQuantity)` etc

Comment: Refer also [HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: @ramiramilu at least it should pass deliveredQuantity textbox ??

Comment: Not if the Id and Name of the textbox do not conform to the format expected by the MVC modelbinder. See Stephen's comment on how to generate the input correctly.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah you are totally right, I thought writing HTML with same name will be enough but it seems i have to write it using Razor, thx Stephen

Comment: thx @Georg Patscheider

Comment: Note that on POST, the html sends fields based on their `name=` *not* the ID.  Your C# will currently only see a single DeliveredQuantity because they all have the same `name=`.  To POST to a 'deliveredquantity' list (`(List<int> devliveredQuantity)`), they need to have different indices, eg `name='DeliveredQuantity[@i]'` - in your case they would be `name='item[@i].DevliveredQuantity'` - but always use `@Html.TextBoxFor` as already advised as this will handle it for you.

Comment: @freedomn-m you are totally right thx brother

Answer (score 0):

By removing HTML code and writing it using Razor problem solved and it now sends the model with the right data